# What is the relationship between `tf.function` and `autograph.to_graph` in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Similar results can be obtained via `tf.function` and `autograph.to_graph`.
However this seems to be version dependant.

For example, the function (taken from the official guide):

```
def square_if_positive(x):
  if x > 0:
    x = x * x
  else:
    x = 0.0
  return x
```

Can be evaluated in graph mode using:

- `autograph.to_graph` in TF 1.14

```
tf_square_if_positive = autograph.to_graph(square_if_positive)

with tf.Graph().as_default():
  g_out = tf_square_if_positive(tf.constant( 9.0))
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(g_out))
```

- `tf.function` in TF2.0

```
@tf.function
def square_if_positive(x):
  if x > 0:
    x = x * x
  else:
    x = 0.0
  return x

square_if_positive(tf.constant( 9.0))
```

So:

- What is the relationship between `tf.function` and `autograph.to_graph`? One can assumes `tf.function` is using `autograph.to_graph` (as well as `autograph.to_code`) internally, but this is far from obvious.
- Is the `autograph.to_graph` snippet still supported in TF2.0 (since it requires `tf.Session`)? It is present in the [autograph doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autograph#automatically_convert_python_control_flow) in TF 1.14, but not in the corresponding doc of TF 2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I covered and answered all your questions in a three-part article: "Analyzing tf.function to discover AutoGraph strengths and subtleties": [part 1](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/03/21/dissecting-tf-function-part-1/), [part 2](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/04/03/dissecting-tf-function-part-2/), [part 3](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/05/10/dissecting-tf-function-part-3/).

To summarize and answer your 3 questions:

- What is the relationship between `tf.function` and `autograph.to_graph`?

`tf.function` uses AutoGraph by default. What happens when you **invoke** the first time a tf.function-decorated function is that:

1. The function body is executed (in TensorFlow 1.x like, thus without eager mode) and its execution is traced (now tf.function knows which nodes are present, which branch of the `if` to keep and so on)
2. At the same time, AutoGraph starts and tries to convert to `tf.*` calls, the Python statements it knows (`while` -> `tf.while`, `if` -> `tf.cond`, ...)-.

Merging the information from points 1 and 2 a new graph is built, and based on the function name and the type of the parameters it is cached in a map (see the articles for a better understanding).

- Is the autograph.to_graph snippet still supported in TF2.0?

Yes, [`tf.autograph.to_graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/autograph/to_graph) is still present and it creates a session internally for you (in TF2 you don't have to worry about them).

At any rate, I suggest you read the three articles linked since they cover in detail this and other peculiarities of `tf.function`.

Comment: Awesome blog posts! (+1)

Comment: How do you use `to_graph` without the `Session` object? [The example of autograph in TF1.14](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autograph#automatically_convert_python_control_flow) is very clear: you use a `tf.Session` with the object generated by a call of your function created by `to_graph`. But in TF2.0, there is no more `tf.Session` directly available.
Moreover, what is the signature of the function returned by `to_graph`? 
In TF1.X, it's a function on the graph objects, but what is going on in TF2.0?

Comment: You can call it: `def square_if_positive` (without the `tf.function` decoration), can be graph converted and executed in this way: `function tf.autograph.to_graph(square_if_positive)` and executed `function(12)`. The function call creates the Session for you

Comment: After some experiments: since `to_graph` is just a transpiler, it doesn't do the casting from `EagerTensors` to `Tensors`. If one adds a `print(type(x))` at the beginning of the function and try to call the two versions (one `@tf.function` decorated and one created by `to_graph`) on an tf.constant, he'll see that the `@tf.function` one works on symbolic tensors, while the `to_graph` one still works on an `EagerTensor`. This is coherent with the [doc of autograph](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/autograph/to_graph): `It does not implement any caching, (...) create any actual ops`

Answer (score 1):

@nessuno 's answer is excellent and it helps me a lot. While, actually the doc [tf.autograph.to_graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/autograph/to_graph) explains the relation ship between autograpsh and tf.funciton directly:

> Unlike tf.function, to_graph is a low-level transpiler that converts Python code to TensorFlow graph code. It does not implement any caching, variable management or create any actual ops, and is best used where greater control over the generated TensorFlow graph is desired. Another difference from tf.function is that to_graph will not wrap the graph into a TensorFlow function or a Python callable. Internally, tf.function uses to_graph.